# pre_get_posts() stops pages from working in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site, based upon the 320 WP-Bootstrap theme, with a custom post type of video. I'm using pre_get_posts() to include the custom post type within the main loop which works perfectly.

When using the function below, links to pages stop working, redirecting to a 404 page.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( (!is_admin()) && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'video' ) );
    return $query;
}
```

I've isolated all changes made to the functions file. Without this query the page links work fine.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking you're not on the admin page and acting on the main query which is great. The part you're missing is checking that you're on an archive.

At the moment no matter what the original query was you're telling it to set the post type to post and video. When you visit a page the query is changed from page to post+video which results in the 404.

Try the following:

```
function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        // Check we're on an archive page.
        if ( $query->is_archive ) { 
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'video' ) );
        }

    }

    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );
```

Comment: This solves the problem I was having but removed cpt from the home page. Testing for is_home() in addition to is_archive() solved that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way the "return $query" is useless since this is an action, not a filter, so you can just remove it or replace it with a plain "return;". Changes to the query object are applied by reference on the original object.